# Why is my Lucene only matching field if I add wildcard to end of value

Tags: java, lucene

Why is my Lucene 4.10 only matching field if I add wildcard to end of value ?

I have a field called acoustid defined with KeywordAnalyzer

```
ACOUSTID("acoustid",IndexFieldTypes.TEXT_NOT_STORED_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS, new KeywordAnalyzer()),
```

If I run my query like this I get no matches

```
query=acoustid:ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855
```

but if add a wildcard I get correct matches

```
query=acoustid:ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855*
```

Note the query is escaped for Lucene before it gets to Lucene

I have another field (reid) that also stores guids using KeywordAnalyzer
and that works fine.

```
query=reid:425cf29a-1490-43ab-abfa-7b17a2cec351
```

I cannot understand this because I don't see how there can be any additional data after the value, and my unit tests such as

```
@Test
public void testFindReleaseByAcoustId() throws Exception {
    Results res = ss.search("acoustid:1d9e8ed6-3893-4d3b-aa7d-6cd79609e389", 0, 10);
    assertEquals(1, res.getTotalHits());
    assertEquals("1d9e8ed6-3893-4d3b-aa7d-6cd79609e386", getReleaseId(res.results.get(0).getDoc()));
}
```

it works fine.

What should my next step be ?

**Update**

Just remembered I added an option to explain the query, so this is with wildcard

```
Query:+acoustid:ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855* +src:1

0:Score:100.0
ba938fab-22b1-42ba-9bda-47261bc0569d:Now That's What I Call the 90s

    2.954172 = (MATCH) sum of:
        0.3385043 = (MATCH) ConstantScore(acoustid:ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855), product of:
            1.0 = boost
            0.3385043 = queryNorm
        2.6156676 = (MATCH) weight(src:1 in 9) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
            2.6156676 = score(doc=9,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0 ), product of:
                0.9409648 = queryWeight, product of:
                    2.779772 = idf(docFreq=2052700, maxDocs=12169449)
                    0.3385043 = queryNorm
                2.779772 = fieldWeight in 9, product of:
                    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
                        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
                    2.779772 = idf(docFreq=2052700, maxDocs=12169449)
                    1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=9)
```

and this is without

```
Query:+(acoustid:ae8f4538 acoustid:9971 acoustid:41b3 acoustid:a6d0 acoustid:bbca1c13e855) +src:1
```

so clearly the '-' hyphens are causing an issue breaking down the terms.

My working query on the similar `reid` gives

Query:+reid:c3c0e462-1606-40dc-9667-1b26b9fb44c5 +src:1

```
0:Score:100.0
c3c0e462-1606-40dc-9667-1b26b9fb44c5:Liquid Tension Experiment

    16.852135 = (MATCH) sum of:
        16.39361 = (MATCH) weight(reid:c3c0e462-1606-40dc-9667-1b26b9fb44c5 in 552496) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
            16.39361 = score(doc=552496,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0 ), product of:
                0.9863018 = queryWeight, product of:
                    16.621292 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=12169449)
                    0.059339657 = queryNorm
                16.621292 = fieldWeight in 552496, product of:
                    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
                        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
                    16.621292 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=12169449)
                    1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=552496)
        0.4585254 = (MATCH) weight(src:1 in 552496) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
            0.4585254 = score(doc=552496,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0 ), product of:
                0.16495071 = queryWeight, product of:
                    2.779772 = idf(docFreq=2052700, maxDocs=12169449)
                    0.059339657 = queryNorm
                2.779772 = fieldWeight in 552496, product of:
                    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
                        1.0 = termFreq=1.0
                    2.779772 = idf(docFreq=2052700, maxDocs=12169449)
                    1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=552496)
```

Ah, I may have found the issue, but will have to rebuild the index to check

reid is defined to use IndexFieldTypes.TEXT_STORED_**NOT_ANALYZED**_NO_NORMS
acoustid is defined to use IndexFieldTypes.TEXT_NOT_STORED_**ANALYZED**_NO_NORMS

Comment: Isn't hyphen (`-`) a special character in lucene queries?

Comment: `Boolean operators allow terms to be combined through logic operators. Lucene supports AND, "+", OR, NOT and "-" as Boolean operators(Note: Boolean operators must be ALL CAPS).`[from docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#-)

Comment: Then one needs to escape that hyphen with a backslash: `\-`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer counts as answer to me...

Comment: @Eugene credited to Lino for the idea. I have no idea about Lucene. It was just a quick google search

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ... which the OP did not do and you did. little, but counts as a research to get the answer in my mind

Comment: Sorry I wasnt the clear, the query is made on a webserver but then the query value is escaped before getting to the Lucene call. It is correctly escape and with the wildcard returns exactly the correct results. (Trying to escape by adding backslashes just creates an invalid query)

Comment: @Eugene I have another field that also uses guid values, and query for that works fine without asterisk e.g query=reid:425cf29a-1490-43ab-abfa-7b17a2cec351

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks but that is not the issue, have added more details to question.

Comment: Hyphens won't be parsed as operators, unless it appears at a location where that would be valid, basically after a space (that is not within a phrase). This will be parsed as an operator: `field:term -term2` and this will not: `field:hypenated-term` (and neither will this: `field:"phrase -terms"`)

Comment: So all problem is that your query *is* analyzed for the `acoustid` field. But field isn't. As far as I remember, `KeywordAnalyzer` is a wrapper for `KeywordTokenizer`, so there is no splitting will be make in QParser... Looks like a small misconfig like query analyzer and index analyzer aren't same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aided by the two previous answers the problem was that the Query analyzer was different to the analyser used when indexing. **But it was not a coding error but a deployment error.**

When I last deployed the index there were two new fields being indexed (not the ones above) and hence the indexing code and classes that define the analysers used for indexing different fields had chnaged. But at the time I didnt deploy updated searcher code because the searcher code itself had not changed, but the indexing library that searcher code uses had changed.

I did actually try to deploy latest search code but I also had another issue regarding JAXB and Java 8/Java 10 and then prevent3ed deplyment. Since I didn't think I needed to redeploy anyway I Left it.

And since the problem was with an old field `acoustid` not a new field I didnt realize the issue was a new issue.

Anyway I solved the JAXB issue and redeployed with latest code base and now search is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
WildcardQuery q = new WildcardQuery(new Term("acoustid", "ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855*");
q.setRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_REWRITE);
Query rewritten = searcher.rewrite(q);
```

and look into rewritten query (via `toString()` or debugger).
`rewritten` will be boolean query made from single term query clauses reflects real index terms.

**UPD**: In Lucene4 middle line should be

```
q.setRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE);
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are getting at here, why do I need to use a Wildcard query

Comment: I propose a debugging approach. As I get from question -- wildcard query works, but term query is not. So we need to find out _why_ wildcard matches. And boolean rewrite will reveal real terms in index that (working) wildcard query matches.

Comment: @Nikolay - I can almost guarantee that a *term* query ( `new TermQuery(new Term("acoustid", "ae8f4538-9971-41b3-a6d0-bbca1c13e855"))` ) would, in fact, work.

Answer (score 1):

Can't give a super concrete answer here, because I don't know what `ss` is. I'm assuming it's layer written in your application to simplify running a lucene search and managing readers, that sort of thing.

I'm assuming `ss.search` looks something like: get an indexreader, open a queryparser and parse the query string, run the query, return `Results` that your application knows how to read.

The problem step here is the queryparser. QueryParser gets passed an analyzer, and if the analyzer doesn't match the field your searching against, you run into problems.  If you analyze a GUID with StandardAnalyzer, you'll end up with a query, post analysis, that looks something like:

```
acoustid:"ae8f4538 9971 41b3 a6d0 bbca1c13e855"
```

Which doesn't match the way it appears in the index. The wildcard query works, because wildcard queries (and fuzzy queries, etc) skip analysis.

As far as why `reid` works, not sure, I'd have to see what `ss.search` looks like. However, if I were to make a bet on it, I'd bet you find a [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html), that reid has a KeywordAnalyzer set up for it, but acoustid doesn't. In that case, add acoustid to the `fieldAnalyzers` list with a `KeywordAnalyzer`, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks your answer prompted me about something , I think I have found the answer see update about IndexFieldTypes.TEXT_NOT_STORED_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS

Comment: Looks like you are using KeywordAnalyzer, though, which doesn't actually do any analysis. Setting it to not analyzed makes sense, but there isn't any functional difference between unanalyzed, and analyzed with KeywordAnalyzer. Your index-time analysis is not the issue, that's why wildcard queries work, it's the QueryParser analysis that is the trouble. Try running an explain on the search for acoustid without the wildcard, see if you get multiple terms in the query.

Comment: Oh I thought that was it :( , Yes I do get multiple terms (see updated question), but I cant find anything special in QueryParser regaridng the different behaviour of these fields.

Comment: As I said, I can't give more detailed guidance on what is going wrong unless I know what `ss` is doing. You would need to post the source code of `ss.search`, or at least how you are using the `QueryParser`.

Comment: Thanks, now fixed it was a deployment issue that caused analyzers to be different at indexing/query time.

Comment: But interesting point you made about wildcards not doing analysis, so does that mean if I rely on analyser to adjust query value for something such as removing underscores and I do wildcard it wont work, whya doesnt wildcard search do anyalsis stage.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - My thought (and I'm not a Lucene dev, so I'm not privy to their reasoning, but it makes sense to me), it's difficult to know how to analyze and apply a wildcard. Analysis is generally used to split text into multiple tokens, so if you how does that play with wildcards? If I'm expecting to find "aide-de-camp" with "aid*amp", that would mean implicitly allowing wildcards to span across multiple other tokens, and including a leading wildcard search, which is a serious performance killer. And that's just one problem, considering the most basic analysis use case (StandardAnalyzer).

Comment: Analyzing partial tokens is also going to be problematic for language-specific analysis, stemmers and phontic analysis, since the rules won't be applied correctly without the full term available. With all the different things analysis can do, there is just a lot of ambiguity in how wildcards, fuzzy queries and the like would need to be handled.